# RubikCube Package - trouble with showing rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use the rubikcube package to get some illustrations but I can't find the error in my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,rubikcube,rubikrotation,rubikpatterns}

\begin{document}
\RubikCubeSolvedWY
\ShowCube{3cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCubeRU}
\quad\Rubik{R}\quad
\RubikRotation{R}
\ShowCube{3cm}{0.7}{\DrawRubikCubeRU}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

So clearly my rotation command didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I have also tried different sample codes from the package documentation but my cubes remain the same and never get rotated.

Comment: You probably didn't run with `--shell-escape` enabled.

Comment: I find this very counter intuitive. Why does this package need to be run with shell escape? I tried, got no error message and a bad rendering. Plus I can't find it in the manual.

Comment: That might be true. Can you tell me how to enable shell-escape for tikz? Or should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @SebGlav extract from `rubikcube` documentation (p.8): _Since the `\RubikRotation` command works by calling the `rubikrotation.pl` program, it follows that the `rubikrotation` package requires (a) Perl to be installed, and (b) the LaTeX engine needs to be run using the `--shell-escape` command-line option._

Comment: OK, thanks. I didn't see it in the first place. I should have search for it.

Comment: @RedLantern if you compile from a terminal/command prompt then it is easy, just add the flag by using a command like `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex` (or `xelatex` or `lualatex` depending on which one you want to use). However, I suppose you use some kind of editor for compiling. The process is different for each editor, so you have to tell us which one it is (maybe TeXstudio or TeXworks? they are commonly used, but there are many others). There are questions here on the site with instructions for the various editors, we can provide links if we know the editor.